# Literature on limit theory

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I wonder, is there a good material on a deep understanding of a theory of limit? I am interested in more complex and advanced limits and the theory around it.

Every literature I went through, basically ends up with l'Hospital.

Comment: Are you interested in limits with more than one variable?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.